# JAVA drawLine with Components

Tags: java, swing, paint

I am trying to draw a line between `JButton`s but my code does not work.
can someone explain me why?

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame x=new JFrame("hello");
    GridLayout gl=new GridLayout(3,3,110,100);

    JButton lb[]=new JButton[9];
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
        lb[i]=new JButton("two");
    x.setLayout(gl);

    for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
        x.add(lb[i]);
    x.pack();
    x.show();
    Graphics y=x.getGraphics();
    y.drawLine((lb[0].getWidth()+lb[1].getX())/2,0 ,(lb[0].getWidth()+lb[1].getX())/2, x.getHeight());
}
```

Comment: If you want to draw, use a drawing surface. X is not a good fit for the last one.

Answer (score 1):

```
 x.show();Graphics y=x.getGraphics();
```

Never use `getGraphics(...)` to do custom painting. That painting will be lost as soon as Swing repaints the component.

Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a component.

So the logic would be to draw the line between the two components and then invoke `super.paintComponent(...)` to that the buttons are painted on top of the line.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) to better understand how this works and for demo code.

Edit:

Example painting code:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    for (int i = 0; i < getComponentCount() - 1; i++)
    {
        Component component1 = getComponent(i);
        Point point1 = component1.getLocation();
        Component component2 = getComponent(i + 1);
        Point point2 = component2.getLocation();

        g.drawLine(point1.x, point1.y, point2.x, point2.y);
    }
}
```

I'll let you modify the code to draw the line from the center of one component to the center of another.